# Selecting all child elements under a div tag in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to search for any children `div` tags under a parent `div` tag, that have text that I'm passing through a variable. I'm using the below `xpath` to do this but I'm getting a

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[(text()='" + variable + "')]")
```

I want to click on on the `div` tag under this parent `div`, that has the exact text from the variable. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I correctly understood your question. Though I will try to give something.

To search for any children `div` tags under a parent `div` tag, the following XPATH could be useful:

```
//div//div[text()='your variable here']
```

The `//` is used to find relative paths. So, what the above XPATH achieves is:

- It finds all the div tags first (`//div`).
- And then it selects those which have any of its child with the given text (`//div[(text()='your variable here']`).

Seeing at your XPATH, I would suggest you use Custom XPATHs as they shall be more helpful in Selenium scripting.

A very handy XPATH cheatsheet can be found here:

https://devhints.io/xpath